# Compute means using number of observations and standard deviation

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

Is it possible to compute mean using standard deviation and number of observations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. Imagine sliding your distribution up and down the number line. The standard deviation and number of observations remain the same, yet the mean changes.